# What is JavaRDD[(Int, String)]?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am using Scala code in my Java App. I have seen return type of one method is `JavaRDD[(Int, String)]`. I do not understand what exactly this will translate to.

For example, `JavaRDD[Int]` is equivalent to `JavaRDD<Integer>` in Java

Comment: You are confused about a list of `(Int, String)` pairs?

Comment: Yes, I have resolved it now. ;) Should I delete this post?

Comment: I don't really know what you were asking, but you're welcome to answer it yourself with your findings. No reason to delete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable of type `JavaRDD[(Int, String)]` in Scala would be a

```
JavaRDD<scala.Tuple2<Int, String>>
```

in Java.